# Observe keyboard notifications *only* from UITextView? Passing UITextView to "object" parameter isn't working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, nsnotificationcenter

Assume a view controller contains both a UITextView and a UITextField. If the goal is to observe keyboard notifications from *only* the UITextView, shouldn't the following code work?

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The function associated with the notification never gets invoked. Is there a way to observe keyboard notifications only from the UITextView?

The reason it matters is because we need to scroll the parent UIView for the UITextView and not for the UITextField. Otherwise, the keyboard obscures the UITextView.

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var promptField: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Get notified when keyboard appears
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: promptField)
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, 
    selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, 
    object: promptField)
```

The result of that code will be that the notification is not sent. The `object` will *never* be the `promptField`. The object is the sender, and it is not the field that shows the keyboard and sends the notification — it's the application.

The question *you* want to ask is probably who is first responder...

Comment: Thanks, Matt! Ultimately, the goal is to only observe notifications from the UITextView. So if we pass `nil` to the object parameter, what else do we need to do?

Comment: The reason it matters is because we need to scroll the parent UIView for the UITextView and not for the UITextField. Otherwise, the keyboard obscures the UITextView.

Comment: Well, I think I already said what else you could do - you could ask the text view whether it's the first responder, right? But in my view it is better to _always_ compensate for the keyboard completely _whenever_ it appears. Your _whole_ interface should be prepared to compensate.

Comment: So that makes sense, but the question still remains of needing to know which field the user is editing ... because the interface will vary based on the field (e.g., keyboard may obscure the UITextView and not the UITextField). Are you suggesting an alternative way of compensating for the keyboard without knowing which field is being edited?

Comment: "but the question still remains of needing to know which field the user is editing" But that, as I keep saying, is the first responder. So, no, I'm not doing anything "without knowing which field is being edited", because I always know, by the time we get to responding to the notification, who the first responder is. For example, if the first responder is a text field and it is above where the keyboard top will be, there is no need to compensate at all.